# Automate daily execution of a Google Collab ipynb

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I want to schedule a Google Collab AI image generator notebook to generate me a new image everyday, and I would want to vary some of the parameters in the notebook each day too (such as the string used to describe the image to be generated).
Is this possible and can someone point me in the right direction of how I might go about doing this with Python or command line?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at **cronjobs**.

Depending on what you what to accomplish I would recommend to have a look at CI/CD basics. E.g. GitHub actions provide you with a simple way to schedule tasks with cron.